# R- Several min values using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a df like this:

```
> head(datamelt)
                  TIMESTAMP ring dendro diameter   ID Rain_mm_Tot year DOY
1373635 2013-05-02 00:00:00    1      1     3405 r1_1           0 2013 122
1373672 2013-05-02 00:15:00    1      1     3417 r1_1           0 2013 122
1373735 2013-05-02 00:30:00    1      1     3417 r1_1           0 2013 122
1373777 2013-05-02 00:45:00    1      1     3426 r1_1           0 2013 122
1373826 2013-05-02 01:00:00    1      1     3438 r1_1           0 2013 122
1373873 2013-05-02 01:15:00    1      1     3444 r1_1           0 2013 122
```

I used ddply to get the min diameter value for each of the year (DOY) in each dendro (dendrometers) in two different ways: i) The first one do its job, giving one value for each day and dendro. nrow(dailymin)=5784. However, I don't know what it does when there are several min values in one day, but in those cases it is not the result I need:

```
library(plyr)
dailymin <- ddply(datamelt, .(year,DOY,ring,dendro), function(x)x[which.min(x$diameter), ])
```

ii) The second way returns several rows for each day if there are several min values, which is OK. nrow(dailymin)=12634:

```
dailymin <- ddply(datamelt, .(year,DOY,ring,dendro), function(x)x[x$diameter==min(x$diameter), ])
```

Here are my questions:
- How is the i) way working when there are several min values?
- And more importantly, in the ii) way, when there are several min values, how can I only have the min that happen further in time? For example, image that for dendro #5 in ring #2 there are 3 min values in 3598mm diameter, happening at 13:15, 13:30 and 13:45. I would like to have only the last one (13:45) and remove the others.

```
> str(dailymin$TIMESTAMP)
 POSIXct[1:12634], format: "2013-05-02 13:45:00" "2013-05-02 08:45:00" "2013-05-02 14:00:00" "2013-05-02 13:45:00" "2013-05-02 14:45:00" ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To your first question: as documented, `which.min` returns the index of the first minimum encountered in `x$diameter`.

To your second question: assuming `x` is already sorted by increasing `TIMESTAMP` (seems to be the case in your example), you can write your own `last.min` function to do exactly like `which.min` does but returns the index of the *last* minimum:

```
last.min <- function(x) length(x) - which.min(rev(x)) + 1L
dailymin <- ddply(datamelt, .(year, DOY, ring, dendro),
                  function(x)x[last.min(x$diameter), ])
```

If your data is not sorted by `TIMESTAMP`, you could use `arrange` to sort it by decreasing `TIMESTAMP`, then use `which.min`:

```
dailymin <- ddply(datamelt, .(year, DOY, ring, dendro),
                  function(x) {
                     x <- arrange(x, desc(TIMESTAMP))
                     x[which.min(x$diameter), ])
                  })
```

Comment: Along the same lines, you could also `order` by `-diameter` (negative for ascending order) and `timestamp` in one swoop and then take the first row in each subsection (e.g, using `head`).

Comment: Yes, although it will be more expensive I believe.